# Mandar request a varios usuarios al mismo tiempo

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs, express

Hare la pregunta dese mi ignorancia ya que recién estoy entrando en el mundo de node js.

Este es el famoso ejemplo del servidor básico en `Node JS`:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server ready'))
```

Donde la ruta principal '\' o `index` devuelve como `response` un "**hola mundo**".

Mi pregunta es, como yo puedo realizar `response` sin `request`?
Mi idea es mandar `response` a muchos usuarios al mismo tiempo, **sin** que me hagan un `request`.

*Esto es una idea de manejar la lógica de un juego online. Un usuario manda un response y el servidor responde con request al resto de los usuarios.*

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Eso no es posible mediante `http` ya que dicho protocolo está basado en lo que se conoce como interacción cliente-servidor. El servidor responde a una solicitud del cliente. Si no hay solicitud, no hay respuesta. Así de simple. Lo que tu quieres se puede lograr mediante otro protocolo, como [`ws`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) por ejemplo. Y en NodeJS es muy popular el uso de [`socket.io`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io) para implementar `ws`. Igual el cliente debe implementar a su vez `ws`. Espero esto te oriente un poco. Saludos

Comment: Es como querer ir en taxi sin poner la mano y/o llamar al taxi. Te sugiero que antes que te pongas a desarrollar, veas los fundamentos de la comunicación en internet. En Youtube hay varios videos, solo es cosa de poner "como funciona internet" y a darle play

Comment: Otra opción sobre `http` sería usar la tecnología [`push`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tecnología_push). La misma es usada por aplicaciones móviles, por ejemplo, o por los servicios de noticias, mediante lo que se conoce como [fuente web](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuente_web). Sin embargo debe existir la suscripción por parte del cliente al canal por el cual el servidor emitirá el contenido actualizado. Una fuente web muy popular es RSS. En fin, opciones tienes, pero es bueno que estudies con detenimiento las mismas para saber cuál te conviene. Saludos

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Quizá te sirva socker.io para una comunicación en tiempo real entre diferentes clientes y el server.

https://socket.io/

Comment: Mas alla de que fue aceptada, esto parece mas un comentario que una respuesta. Es mas, ya estaba en los comentarios esto.

Answer (score -1):

Es imposible, el protocolo http y https no funciona de esa manera, siempre tiene que haber un *request* y un *response*. Los juegos online funcionan con protocolos UDP y TCP, UDP te permite hacer lo que dices ya que el protocolo no requiere confirmación, solo manda y manda datos.